# Парсинг. Пустые строки

Tags: python, парсер

Уважаемые программисты, помогите пожалуйста, при проверке кода выпадают пустые квадратные скобки, а должен быть перечень улиц. Код:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

r = requests.get ("https://xn--80ap2aj.xn--80asehdb/40c6863e-2a5f-4033-a377-3416533948bd/")
sait = BS(r.content, 'html.parser')


for el in sait.select("div.col-md-3.col-sm-6"):
    title = el.select ('zn_id > a')
    print(title)
```

Answer (score 1):

Проблема во втором селекторе: `zn_id > a`. В найденных элементах нет тега `zn_id`. Такого тега, собственно, вообще не существует. Если заменить селектор на `a`, то Вы найдёте теги, содержащие названия улиц.

Но все улицы можно найти и в одном селекторе: `div.col-md-3.col-sm-6 > a`.

***Пример:***

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('https://xn--80ap2aj.xn--80asehdb/40c6863e-2a5f-4033-a377-3416533948bd/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

for a in soup.select('div.col-md-3.col-sm-6 > a'):
    print(a.text)
```

***stdout:***

```
1-й Проезд
1-й Авдотьинский Переулок
1-й Бабушкина Переулок
...
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное!